# <p:schedule> problem inside <ui:composition><ui:define>...<ui:define/><ui:composition/>

Tags: jsf-2

I am using p:schedule inside my project. It simply works with new fresh application and in the project also. But when i put this in project's template format 
ui:composition
   ui:define
      p:schedule
       ...
   ui:define
ui:composition

then its not showing the schedular, as other components are showing???
Any kind suggestion will be appreciated. Immediate requirement :-(

Answer (score 0):

It's a well known issue with Facelets.

As it is recommended [here](http://users.tpg.com.au/adslkpp9/facelets/troubleshooting.html), *Use <c:if> and <ui:include> only for clearly different chunks of xhtml.
Enclose components in panels if you need to make them more unique.
If you must, provide IDs, but beware that two included chunks of xhtml as siblings will cause you a Duplicate ID problem.
For minor UI customisation depending on the state of the application, use the JSF component property, rendered="true/false".*

If you use PrimeFaces, I can suggest you to use p:outputPanel component with rendered attribute instead of c:if.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but its not working :-( plz can u provide some example code. Here is my code:              sry its not accepting th code as exceeding th length...

Comment: <ui:composition template="./../common/editScreenTmpl.xhtml">
 <ui:define name="title">#{actionController.screenTitle}</ui:define>
  <ui:param name="beanName" value="${scr1015.scr1015}" />
   <ui:define name="center">
    <h:inputHidden value="#{scr1015.preformload}" />
      <p:schedule value="#{scr1201.eventModel}" rendered="true"...</p:schedule> </p:outputPanel> <p:outputPanel id="dialog"> <p:dialog ...>
 <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" ...>
... </h:panelGrid> </p:dialog>  <h:inputHidden id="ith0003" binding="#{scr1015.postformload}" />
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>